# Got a php script that downloads many images from url, can i make the script work faster?

Tags: php

First i make an array of urls that contain an image (1 url = 1 image, nothing else in that url):

```
$image_endings = array();
for($x=1;$x<=25;$x++) {
    for($y=1;$y<=48;$y++) {
        $image_endings[] ="${x}n${y}w.png";
    }
}
```

Now i run each url and if that url exists, i donwload the image:

```
foreach ($image_endings as $se){
    $url = 'http://imgs.xkcd.com/clickdrag/'.$se;

if (@GetImageSize($url)) {

//echo  "image exists ";
    $img = file_get_contents($url);
    file_put_contents("tiles/".$se,$img);

    $width = 50;
    $height = 50;
    $filename = 'tiles/'.$se;
    $image = imagecreatefrompng ( $filename );
    $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor ( $width, $height ); // new wigth and height
    imagealphablending($new_image , false);
    imagesavealpha($new_image , true);
    imagecopyresampled ( $new_image, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, imagesx ( $image ), imagesy ( $image ) );
    $image = $new_image;

    // saving
    imagealphablending($image , false);
    imagesavealpha($image , true);
    imagepng ( $image, $filename );

} else {

// echo  "image does not exist ";
```

}

The problem with this script - it takes ~5minutes to completely finish. I was wondering if i can make it run faster?

Comment: Are you scraping xkcd.com?

Comment: Shouldn't `$image_endings[] ="${x}n${y}w.png";` be `$image_endings[] ="{$x}n{$y}w.png";` ? ie, you're not surrounding your variable names in braces properly.

Comment: if you are taking images from remote URL and having nested loop 25 x 48 will surely take much time...

Comment: @John Conde, i dont know what means scraping.

Comment: @Sepster hmm it works how it is now, ill try changing it but i dont think it will matter

Comment: [screen/web scraping](https://www.google.com/search?q=screen+scrap9ing&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS517US517&aq=f&oq=screen+scrap9ing&aqs=chrome.0.57.2370&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS517US517&q=screen+scraping&spell=1&sa=X&ei=wz5UUe2jH6vl4APLhIDwDA&ved=0CDEQvwUoAA&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44342787,d.dmg&fp=a4329d359ff42ae5&biw=1256&bih=772)

Comment: You are downloading every file twice (`GetImageSize()` and `file_get_contents()`) and you are writing it into a file twice (`file_put_contents()` and then again with `imagepng()`) ... there is potential for optimization.
On a side note ... there are already multiple scripts that download the clickdrag images from xkcd and create a large image out of it ... is there a reason you are writing another one?

Comment: BTW, just did some calculations. 25 * 48 images makes 1200 images that need to be downloaded. With a runtime of 5 minutes (300 seconds) that makes 300 / 1200 = 0,25 seconds per image. I don't think you will get much less than that, considering the overhead of every http request.

Comment: @Gerald Schneider just got a task to make a script myself, plus i couldnt find anything in php for what i doing

Answer (score 0):

Rather than checking `GetImageSize` on each one, as this probably takes unnecessary time, how about just checking it the once (when you go to get it):

```
...

foreach ($image_endings as $se){
    $url = 'http://imgs.xkcd.com/clickdrag/'.$se;

/* Don't do this... time consuming...
if (@GetImageSize($url)) {
echo  "image exists ";
*/


$img = file_get_contents($url);

// Check here if it existed.
if ($img !== false) {

    file_put_contents("tiles/".$se,$img);
...
```

And as per @GeraldSchneider's comment... is the `file_put_contents(...)` necessary?

Comment: I guess he wants to save a resized version of the downloaded image. I'd replace `imagecreatefrompng()` with `imagecreatefromstring($img)` and remove the `file_put_contents()` call. That way it is only written once to file.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Agreed; He should use the memory stream he already has, rather than creating and then reading a file stream.  While the internet I/O is clearly going to be _the_ bottleneck here, this (potentially) unnecessary disk I/O certainly won't be helping.